# Webflux: Microservice A POST to Microservice B

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-webflux

I guess my answer is already on this forum (because I read), but I can not understand my concern ...

I want microservice A to send a POST to microservice B.

microserviceA:

```java
webClientBuilder.build().post().uri("http://localhost:9644/relever/add")
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .body(Mono.just(releve), Web.class)
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(Web.class);
```

microservice B (controller):

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/relever")
public class ReleverController {


    @PostMapping("/add")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void AjouteDunRelever(Relever relever) {
        System.out.println("ok!!!");
    }
}
```

When I use POSTMAN in POST mode to `http://localhost:9644/relever/add`, microservice B reacts, but when microservice A post to microservice B, microservice B does not react, ... why?

thank you!

Comment: First I think the post request from Postman should be `localhost:9644/relever/add` or am I wrong? And do you get any errors or something else? Have you already gone through a [tutorial](https://lankydan.dev/2018/03/15/doing-stuff-with-spring-webflux)?

Comment: Yes the URL of POSTMAN is this (in post): [http://localhost:9644/relever/add]

Comment: OK like this:it works:  WebClient client = WebClient.create(localhost:9644) 
but with webClientBuilder.build().post().uri() it does not work.I need to use the loadbalancer, because instead of localhost there will be the name of microserviceB

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the baseUrl before building the client.

Try

```
webClientBuilder.baseUrl("http://localhost:9644").build().post().uri("/relever/add")
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .body(Mono.just(releve), Web.class)
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(Web.class);
```

WebClient.create(baseUrl) is basically just doing that for you.
From: **org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient**

```
     * Variant of {@link #create()} that accepts a default base URL. For more
     * details see {@link Builder#baseUrl(String) Builder.baseUrl(String)}.
     * @param baseUrl the base URI for all requests
     * @see #builder()
     */
    static WebClient create(String baseUrl) {
        return new DefaultWebClientBuilder().baseUrl(baseUrl).build();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but either I wrote it wrong, but webClientBuilder does not work (neither in localhost, nor with the name of the microservice)

But above all, what I do not understand is that with another microservice in .get I have no problem .... webClientBuilder.build().get()
            .uri("http://mc-societes//societes/list")
            .exchange()
            .flatMapMany(response -> response.bodyToFlux(Societe.class))

Comment: Have you tried to debug and see what status code you get back?

Like 

webClientBuilder.baseUrl("http://localhost:9644").build().post().uri("/relever/add")
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .body(Mono.just(releve), Web.class)
    .exchange()
    .flatMap(res -> res.statusCode)


and set a breakpoint at res.statusCode

Comment: I don't know if you got a notification, but I created a new question here to better explain

Answer (score 0):

I changed the baseurl to localhost and with the microservice name, no reaction!

```
webClientBuilder.baseUrl("http://localhost:9644").build().post().uri("/relever/add")
.body(Mono.just(releve), Web.class)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .exchange()
  .flatMap(response -> {
                    System.out.println(response.statusCode());
                System.out.println(); **<---- Breakpoint Here**
                return response.bodyToMono(Web.class);
                });
```

at the top of my class I do this:

```
@Autowired
    private WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;
```

and in another package I load the loadbalancer

```
@Configuration

public class Config {
    private static final org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger logger
        = LogManager.getLogger(Config.class.getName());

    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public WebClient.Builder loadBalancedWebClientBuilder() {
        return WebClient.builder();
    }
}
```

The breakpoint doesn't even stop (so it never goes into flatmap), and no reaction in the microserviceB controller

Thank you